# PHP has encountered an Access Violation at ***

Tags: php, iis

Win 2003, PHP 5.2.12 and IIS 6.

I have PHP configured as ISSAPI and it is serving PHP pages. When I try a page that requires MySQL I am getting just:

PHP has encountered an Access Violation at (and a RANDOM number)

What does this mean?

I have mysql extension uncommented in php.ini, iUSR_ has write permissions. I have specified the php extension directory in php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that also occured in PHP5 RC3 as referenced here:
http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=28799

The IIS6 server will randomly throw an error like: PHP has encountered
an Access Violation at 017AE084

Comment: @streetparade - Yes 5 years ago!